# Why does ( true && 1 ) return 1, but ( 1 && true ) returns true?

Tags: javascript

In C I know true and false evaluate to 1 and 0 respectively. `show` in this case just prints to the screen... Not sure what's going on here. I'm expecting to get `true` back. This `1` is messing up my karma.

```
show(1 && true);
true



show(true && 1);
1
```

Comment: I would just like to point out that this kind of behavior is pretty common in dynamic languages that let you use any value in a boolean context (Javascript, Python, Lua, etc). C is also a weird corner case since it doesn't have a separate boolean type and therefore mixes uses ints for that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply put - that's how `&&` is defined.  In Javascript, `a && b` returns `a` if `a` is falsy and `b` if `a` is truthy.

Conversely `a || b` returns `a` if `a` is truthy and `b` if `a` is falsy.

This makes sense intuitively - if `a` is false in `a && b`, then why bother reading the rest of the expression?  You already know the whole thing is false. So just return false. But Javascript makes the decision to return `a`, which is falsy, instead of making up the value `false` to return out of nowhere.

This is based on short-circuit evaluation common to all C-style languages.

It allows for much expressiveness in Javascript. For instance this pattern:

```
var foo = function(opts) {
    opts = opts || {}
    // ...
}
```

Implements an optional parameter `opts`.  If `opts` is not passed in at all, `opts = opts || {}` will set `opts` to `{}`, so the rest of the code does not have to know `opts` wasn't passed.

In long-hand it is equivalent to the following:

```
var x = a || b; // is equivalent to
var x;
if(a) {
    x = a;
}
else {
    x = b;
}
```

and

```
var y = a && b; // is equivalent to
var y;
if(!a) {
     y = a;
}
else {
    y = b;
}
```

Therefore Javascript can be much more terse than C or Java, because simple `if` statements can be replaced by `||` or `&&` entirely. Sometimes this makes the code more terse and less readable and more like Perl, other times it allows for new Javascript patterns, like `opts = opts || {}`.

Another use is in patterns like

```
var displayName = user.fullname || user.email;
```

Which means "use the full name if available; if not, fall back to email."  I personally find this expressive and readable, but it's arguably terse and obscure depending on which part of the Javascript community you hail from.  Because of examples like this, and essentially the fact that truthy values are far more diverse then falsy values, using short-circuit `||` is much more common than short-circuit `&&`, as in your question.

Comment: Is it fairly common in Javascript to use the && || convention for simple if statements? I like how concise it is.

Comment: @KeithGrout both examples I gave are used in production code in my company.  It is arguably terse and "clever" and unreadable but many people accept it as a common pattern.  It's your judgment call.

Comment: I like to use this trick to declare and not overwrite global namespaces or variables: `window.foo || (window.foo = {});`